# Ruby converting string to array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have the following string.

```
key = "John Clark\nDallas\nSystem Engineer\nGlobal Edge\nWage 2\nY\n1\nRobin James\nCleveland\nArchitect\nMaxSys\nWage 3\nY\n0\nJoseph Neils\nLittle Rock\nDB Admin\nTech Sys\nWage 2\nY\n1\n"
```

I want to convert this string to an array of arrays. Each array should consist of 7 members. The end result should be like this:

```
[["John Clark","Dallas","System Engineer","Global Edge","Wage 2","Y","1"],["Robin James","Cleveland","Architect","MaxSys","Wage 3","Y","0"],["Joseph Neils","Little Rock","DB Admin","Tech Sys","Wage 2","Y","1"]]
```

If the number of lines in `key` is not evenly divisible by `7` the last array should contain the leftovers.

How can I do this Ruby?

Comment: You say you have a “hash”, but it looks like you have two strings.

Comment: How does `value = "gLFyf-gsfi"` play together with the string before?

Comment: When I collect all nested divs inside another div as hashes from a webpage, this is what I get. The class name of the outer div is collected as "gLFyf-gsfi" and values of all other inner divs are collected as one string in the key !

Comment: You don't have a hash. You have two strings and only the first one is relevant to the question. That's why you've received the downvote. I suggest you edit to remove reference to a hash and remove `value = "gLFyf-gsfi"`. You need to also state what is to be done if the number of lines in `key` is not divisible by `7`. Is the last array to contain the "leftovers"?

Comment: I trust you do not object to my edit. You had not reappeared, and there are 4 votes to close, so I decided to go ahead with an edit. If I've misrepresented your question, correct it with an edit, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split your string like this:

```
string = "John Clark\nDallas\nSystem Engineer\nGlobal Edge\nWage 2\nY\n1\nRobin James\nCleveland\nArchitect\nMaxSys\nWage 3\nY\n0\nJoseph Neils\nLittle Rock\nDB Admin\nTech Sys\nWage 2\nY\n1\n"

string.split("\n").each_slice(7).to_a
#=> [["John Clark", "Dallas", "System Engineer", "Global Edge", "Wage 2", "Y", "1"], ["Robin James", "Cleveland", "Architect", "MaxSys", "Wage 3", "Y", "0"], ["Joseph Neils", "Little Rock", "DB Admin", "Tech Sys", "Wage 2", "Y", "1"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be using the `value` variable you're defining, but you can convert the string you assigned to `key` to the output you provided using `split` and `each_slice`:

```
array_of_values = key.split("\n")
# => ["John Clark", "Dallas", ... ]

groups_of_seven = array_of_values.each_slice(7)
# => #<Enumerator: ["John Clark", "Dallas", ...]

groups_of_seven.first
# => ["John Clark", "Dallas", "System Engineer", "Global Edge", "Wage 2", "Y", "1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply spliting a string of newline separated fields. The String object in Ruby has a split method that does that.

```
my_string = "John Clark\nDallas\nSystem Engineer\nGlobal Edge\nWage 2\nY\n1\nRobin James\nCleveland\nArchitect\nMaxSys\nWage 3\nY\n0\nJoseph Neils\nLittle Rock\nDB Admin\nTech Sys\nWage 2\nY\n1\n"
my_string.split("\n")
```

gives you an array of strings like the one you want. Then you can combine these arrays into another array.

There's documentation about the split method here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/String.html#method-i-split